# Possibility to re-order bars in a stacked bar chart based on click Vega-lite

Tags: vega-lite

Is it Possible to re-order the bars in a stacked bar chart based on click Vega-lite?

In the example below I have added a separate "Legend" chart where a user can click to focus on a particular weather type. When clicked, I want that weather group to shift to the bottom of the stacks so it appears at the bottom and we can see the trend clearly. Otherwise it is not possible to see the actual trend. Maybe I could add a line chart layer also.

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {"url": "data/seattle-weather.csv"},
  "vconcat": [
    {
      "title": "Combined",
      "mark": {
        "type": "bar",
        "cornerRadiusTopLeft": 1,
        "cornerRadiusTopRight": 1
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"timeUnit": "month", "field": "date", "type": "ordinal"},
        "y": {
          "aggregate": "count",
          "stack": "zero",
          "sort": {"op": "sum", "field": "count", "order": "descending"}
        },
        "color": {"field": "weather", "legend": null},
        "opacity": {
          "condition": {"selection": "weather_selected", "value": 1},
          "value": 0.1
        }
      },
      "transform": [
        {
          "calculate": "datum.weather == weather_selected ? 1 : 0",
          "as": "color_order"
        },
        {
          "calculate": "datum.weather == weather_selected ? 0 : 1",
          "as": "color_order2"
        }
      ],
      "selection": {
        "weather_selected": {
          "type": "multi",
          "fields": ["weather"],
          "empty": "all",
          "bind": "legend"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "title": null,
      "width": 27,
      "height": 10,
      "align": "center",
      "mark": {"type": "circle", "size": 200},
      "encoding": {
        "column": {
          "field": "weather",
          "type": "nominal",
          "header": {"title": null}
        },
        "color": {
          "field": "weather",
          "scale": {"range": ["#1f77b4", "#ff7f0e", "#2ca02c", "#d62728"]}
        },
        "opacity": {
          "condition": {"selection": "weather_selected", "value": 1},
          "value": 0.1
        }
      },
      "selection": {
        "weather_selected": {
          "type": "single",
          "fields": ["weather"],
          "empty": "none",
          "init": {"weather": "sun"}
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "config": {}
}
```

Comment: You could but it wouldn't be a good user experience in my opinion, especially for the amount of work involved. Why not just use a grouped bar chart instead so you can easily compare and then use the clicks to highlight the values you want.

Comment: I was hoping there was a simple transform we could apply to do a refresh and re-sort.
I can do this outside of vega-lite using another method but I thought this could add some nice functionality to stacked bar charts. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked this out. Sharing for the community.
Click a legend item and it resorts the stacks and lightens the other stacks.

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {"url": "data/barley.json"},
  "params": [
    {
      "name": "click_FILTER",
      "select": {"type": "point", "encodings": ["color"], "fields": ["site"]},
      "bind": "legend"
    }
  ],
  "transform": [
    {
      "calculate": "if(click_FILTER.site && datum.site === click_FILTER.site[0], 0, if(datum.site === 'Crookston', 1, 2))",
      "as": "siteOrder"
    }
  ],
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"aggregate": "sum", "field": "yield"},
    "y": {"field": "variety", "sort": "-x"},
    "color": {"field": "site"},
    "order": {"field": "siteOrder"},
    "opacity": {
      "condition": {"param": "click_FILTER", "value": 1},
      "value": 0.5
    }
  },
  "config": {}
}
```